# Can I get the data types of the headers of all sheets in an excel file, uploaded on reactJS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, npm

There are three data types in excel which I need to get:

- varchar
- number
- date

**Sample excel screenshots:**
[Sheet 1 from excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axG3z.png)
[Sheet 2 from same excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHgEZ.png)

eg. In,

```
sheet 1 = [number, varchar, number, date, varchar]
sheet 2 = [number, varchar]
```